# Adding a image in Pug in the latest version

Tags: node.js, server, pug

I am trying to learn PugJS and I am trying to learn on how to add a image in the latest version, I tried both ways, the Html way in pug, and the CSS way, but none are working, how do I implement a image into pug

Comment: How are you compiling the Pug? Are you using Express, Gulp, or just the node package?

Answer (score 1):

It depends where you're referencing your images. If you're hosting your own images, then create a `public` directory and place all images there. Tell Express where to find them:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

In your `views/index.pug` file, you'd reference them without a relative path like so:

```
img(src='test.jpg', alt='login', style='width:100px;height:100px;')
```